# How to get values from dynamic form, pass them to a variable and redirect to a URL with query string parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin (php: contact form 7) that creates a form and sends the data to an email when the user clicks the send button.

I need to be able to capture all the form's fields and pass them to a URL, so that I can capture the info and store it in a SQL database.

So far, this is my code:

```
$form.submit( function( event ) {
        if ( typeof window.FormData !== 'function' ) {
            return;
        }

        wpcf7.submit( $form );
        event.preventDefault();

        var refillQuiz2 = function ($form, items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, n) {
                $form.find(':input[name="' + i + '"]').val('');
                $form.find(':input[name="' + i + '"]').siblings('span.wpcf7-quiz-label').text(n[0]);
                $form.find('input:hidden[name="_wpcf7_quiz_answer_' + i + '"]').attr('value', n[1]);
            });

        };
        //alert(refillQuiz2[1]);

        window.location.replace("http://www.unicoc.edu.co/mkt/captura.aspx?" + refillQuiz2.value);
    } );
```

It send the email, and redirects to the URL without problem, but the URL that I'm getting is "http://www.unicoc.edu.co/mkt/captura.aspx?undefined"

I need that if the form has 4 fields the url looks like this "http://www.unicoc.edu.co/mkt/captura.aspx?prm1=TEXT&prm2=TEXT&prm3=TEXT&prm4=TEXT"

How can I capture the $form items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set refillQuiz2 = function...
so the function itself is stored in refillQuiz2.

If you then want to get the value from refillQuiz2.value it is undefined.
I am not sure but I guess on this line you want to set the value to retrieve

```
$form.find('input:hidden[name="_wpcf7_quiz_answer_' + i + '"]').attr('value', n[1]);
```

write the value you want into a variable  return it.
Then you could call refillQuiz2() [because there is a function stored in it which will return whatever you like]

PS: If you console.log(refillQuiz2) you see that there is just a function stored in it which has no value attribute.

I hope this helps